# document.title returns undefined. Why is this?

Tags: javascript, html, css, properties, title

I have this variable here:

```
var money=0;
```

This variable updates constantly so keep that in mind. I'm using the property

```
document.title
```

to display the variable "money" in the page title like this:

```
var money=0;
document.title = money;
```

When i refresh the page, the title says undefined so i'm guessing

```
document.title
```

returned undefined. Why is this? also, would the variable "money" constantly get updated in the pages title? If not, how could i make that happen? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assigning this:

```
document.title = money;
```

Does a one-time assignment of the value in `money` to the `document.title`.  Any further changes to `money` will not be reflected in the `document.title` unless you assign it again.

If you are seeing `undefined` in the title after doing the above assignment, then that can only be because `money` is not yet declared or initialized so it doesn't yet have a value or something has set its value to `undefined`.

---

If you want the title of the document to regularly reflect the value in your `money` variable, then the best way is to make a short little function that you can call to update the `money` variable rather than updating it directly and that short little function will also update the title for you:

```
function updateMoney(val) {
    money = val;
    document.title = val;
}
```

Then, anytime you want to change the `money` value, you simply call:

```
updateMoney(100);
```

And, both things will be updated for you.

---

It is also possible to create a recurring timer that will constantly copy the money value to the title, but that is a lot less efficient (particularly on battery-operated devices).

Answer (score 1):

i would prefer you to use jQuery instead:

```
var money=0;
$('title').text(money);
```

Comment: Why would this do anything different than the OP already has?  Also, it is customary here on SO to not offer a jQuery solution unless jQuery is mentioned in the question (in tags or text).

Comment: @jfriend00 can you tell why you down voted??? Is my answer is wrong???

And also i suggested jQuery coz of he might not aware of jQuery

Comment: I didn't downvote, but your answer does not offer a solution to the OP's problem so it probably deserves a downvote.  And, as I said, you should not be offering jQuery solutions unless jQuery was requested.  Also, jQuery offers nothing useful or unique for this particular problem so it's inefficient to even use it for this.